# React Leaflet, convert GeoJSON coordinates to Leaflet format

Tags: leaflet, geojson, react

I am trying to plot a GeoJSON using Leaflet. I know the order of co-ords is different for GeoJSON and leaflet ([long, lat] vs[lat, long]).

Here is my GeoJSON file :

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "GID": "AFG"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    63.6209,
                    29.4693
                ],
                [
                    63.6194,
                    29.4693
                ],
                [
                    63.6168,
                    29.4695
                ],
                [
                    63.6143,
                    29.4699
```

How do I convert these into React Leaflet standard and plot them?

Here is my current Leaflet code. It only shows the map with no polygon on it right now.

```
 <MapContainer center={[43.38621, -79.83713]}
                            zoom="13"
                            scrollWheelZoom={false}
                            style={{ height: "80vh" }}>
                            <TileLayer
                                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                            />
                            {console.log(mapt)}
                            {mapt.length > 0 &&
                                <GeoJSON key='my-geojson' data={mapt.json} style={{ color: "blue" }} coordsToLatLng />
                            }

                        </MapContainer>
```

mapt is where I am passing my GeoJSON file shown at the start.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code of what you have so far, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: leaflet has plugins that can deal with geoJSON data directly, and I'm not sure what "leaflet format" means here either. Show some code?

Comment: What is `mapt.json`? It should be GeoJSON object.

Comment: @TomazicM mapt is where the geojson file is. So I just write it as mapt?

Comment: If you want to get your GeoJSON from file, you first have to load/get/fetch it with some form of AJAX, see https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html.

Comment: @TomazicM I already have the file from the backend in React as a prop which is named mapt.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with React, so I can't be of much further help here.